# How to run t-test with subset of rows in R

Tags: r, subset, t-test

Below is a part of my data (pairht_protein)

[image]

I am trying to run t-test on all the variables (columns) between two groups which are:

```
Resistant_group <- c(PAIR-01, PAIR-12, PAIR-09)
Sensitive_group <- c(PAIR-07, PAIR-02, PAIR-05)
```

Before I make a function I tired to pick one of the variables and tried:

```
t.test(m_pHSL660 ~ Subject, data = subset(pairht_protein, Subject %in% c("Resistant_group", "Sensitive_group")))
```

But it gave me an error  : `'grouping factor must have exactly 2 levels'`

Is there a way to run t-test between these groups? and possibly make it as a function?

Comment: I think, you have a problem with the group definition. Try to define them as: c("PAIR-01", "PAIR-12", "PAIR-09"). And the same for Sensitive_group. And, in the subsetting part, drop out the quotations marks, like: c(Resistant_group, Sensitive_group)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you must correct how you define the groups (you cannot use dashes on variable names):

```
Resistant_group <- c('PAIR-01', 'PAIR-12', 'PAIR-09')
Sensitive_group <- c('PAIR-07','PAIR-02','PAIR-05')
```

Then, using `dplyr` package create another factor variable with only two levels:

```
library(dplyr)

# assuming pairht_protein is your dataset name

pairht_protein <- pairht_protein %>% mutate(sub = case_when( subject %in% Resistant_group ~1,
                                  subject %in% Sensitive_group ~2),
                          sub = as.factor(sub))
```

Because this new variable is going to make NAs values for elements outside your groups, you don't need to subsetting:

```
t.test(m_pHSL660 ~ sub, data =pairht_protein)
```

Comment: I think it’s almost working except that when I run the t-test, I get a message like: ‘grouping factor must have exactly 2 levels’

Comment: Sorry. I just edited my answer. Try again the last command please.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you!

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please accept it and close the question.